# Can this Submit button be moved?

Tags: html, css

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/m3xjV/) JSfiddle have I made a form without using tables.

The problem is that I can't get the submit button on the same line as "Type" and below the End Data field.

Does anyone know how to do that?

HTML

```
<div class="create-new">
    <div id="create_result" style="display:none;">
    </div>
    <form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
        <input name="anchor" id="anchor" value="create" type="hidden">

        <label class="new" for="title">Title:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" name="title" id="title" />

        <label class="new" for="owner">Owner:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" name="owner" id="owner" /><br class="new"/>

        <label class="new" for="users">Users:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" name="users" id="users"/>


        <label class="new" for="groups">Groups:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" name="groups" id="groups" /><br class="new"/>

        <label class="new" for="begin_date">Begin Date:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" id="from" name="from"/>

        <label class="new" for="end_date">End Date:</label>
        <input class="new" type="text" id="to" name="to"/><br class="new"/>

        <label class="new" for="type">Type:</label>

        <input name="ctype" id="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel <br/>
        <input name="ctype" id="ctypee" value="course"    type="radio" /> Course <br/>

        <button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label.new, input.new, select.new, textarea.new { display: block; float: left; width: 150px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
label.new { width: 110px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 2px; }
textarea.new { height: 50px; }
br.new { clear: left; }
i    nput.n { display: block; float: right; width: 150px; }
.create-new { display: inline-block; position: relative; left: 25%; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `input.n` to `button.n` and adjusted the styles to `display:inline`

`button.n { display: inline; float: right; width: 150px; }`

I also moved the button placement in your code to right under the label

```
<label class="new" for="type">Type:</label>

<button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>

<input name="ctype" id="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/CKC29/

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to put the items into a list (ul) then in your CSS set `display: inline;` for the two elements you would like to be on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

Add the `button.n` selector to the first two label lines on top, so that it does the same as the labels so as the label with type.

```
button.n, label.new, input.new, select.new, textarea.new { display: block; float: left; width: 150px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
button.n, label.new { width: 110px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 2px; }
```

If the class name of `n` was a typo in your code above, just take the right classname, probably `new` instead of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing it changing only the css is to set "display:inline" for the inputs that preceed your submit buttom.